# Windows 7 takes 4 minutes to mount a USB mass storage device

Tags: storage, usb

I Have a custom USB Mass Storage Device that has been used in Windows XP for years as part of a product. In XP, the device mounts within seconds, with a drive letter and a window. In Windows 7, it takes 4 minutes to do the same. What is the difference between the way Windows 7 and Windows XP mounts a USB Mass storage device?

Comment: What size? Filesystem?

Comment: Windows 7 is nosy too, it scans all the files on the drive to see what options to present you on it's little pop-up menu... pictures, music, programs.    "Show me my files Dangit!!"  is the option I always want... knock it off!

Answer (score 1):

Windows 7 performs a consistency check when USB storage is mounted, though I don't know the exact details of the process. I have a couple thumbdrives that I sometimes mount in Linux that always get a little hiccup from Windows 7 the next time I move them over after messing with files.