# Windows 10 mounts USB drive after 6 minute delay

Tags: windows-10, usb, drivers, mount, device-manager

I have a Windows Compact 2013 embedded device with two data stores (one Flash memory and one SD Card). I connect this device to any Windows 7, 8 or 10 PC, and the two data stores mount straight away as two drives (J: and K: for example)

However, on one particular PC (Windows 10 Pro, OS Build 15063.413), there is a 6 minute delay before the drives are mounted.

I can connect other USB mass storage devices using the same USB port, any they mount straight away.

If I look inside Device Manager on the problem PC, I can see the two new "USB Device" entries under "Disk Drives", and two new "USB Mass Storage Device" entries under "Universal Serial Bus controllers", both of which appear within a couple of seconds of connecting the device.

So in summary:

- Insert USB cable
- approx 1-2 seconds later, new entries appear in Device manager
- 6 minutes later the drives both mount and pop up in Windows Explorer

I have tried removing the files on the flash drive and SD Card so that there are empty file systems, but this makes no difference, there is still a 6 minute delay. (I found [this reference](https://superuser.com/questions/437034/windows-7-takes-4-minutes-to-mount-a-usb-mass-storage-device) regarding consistency checks, but unfortunately it doesn't seem to offer a solution).

Using a smaller SD Card makes no difference to the timings (I cannot change the size of the flash as it is built in)

I have checked the AutoPlay settings to ensure that they are set to "Open folder to view files (File Explorer)". I've also tried other settings for AutoPlay.

I have also tried uninstalling and reinstalling the device drivers, updating the drivers, but nothing seems to fix the problem on this one PC.

This PC and device used to work fine together about a month ago, and the drives would mount quickly (4-6 seconds). The problem started occurring following the first set of Windows system updates after the WannaCry attack (I don't believe that the WannaCry attack itself is relevant here, just the timing of the Windows update). I have tried rolling back the updates, and also allowed further updates, but nothing seems to fix the problem.

I've been trying to search for anyone who has been having similar problems, but have not been successful. Does anyone have any ideas about what might be going wrong? What is Windows doing when I attach the device? And how can I fix the problem?

Comment: Have you tried the two problem devices in another machine?

Comment: Yes, (it is actually one device, two drives). The device works fine when connected to any other Windows 7, 8 or 10 PC, also if I take other instances of this device (we have dozens), the behaviour is the same. If I connect one of these devices to the problem machine I see a 6 minute delay, but connecting them to any other Windows 7, 8, 10 PC, and they work immediately, so it seems to be the PC that has the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks to Richard Brodie. Your advice did lead me to a solution.

I had been investigating the event log for each individual USB store on the device, However, when I checked the USB 3.0 controller, there was a "Device Not Migrated" message in the event log.

A search lead me to [this page](https://www.drivereasy.com/knowledge/device-not-migrated-error-on-windows-10-solved/).

Step 1 didn't help, and I didn't use their software, however step 4 was the charm.

Uninstalling the USB Root Hub (USB 3.0) driver, followed by a restart, and now the PC mounts the USB drives on this device.

Thanks for the invaluable lead.

Answer (score 1):

I have been chasing a similar problem on a friend's laptop with a USB flash drive which started after a recent Windows 10 update. It has been suggested that it is [Bluetooth related](https://forums.windowscentral.com/windows-10/373096-windows-10-slow-detect-usb-connected-devices.html). Try checking the system event log at around the insertion time, particularly for references to BTHUSB.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion. I followed your instructions and the link. The discussion was useful, and quite interesting, but unfortunately Bluetooth didn't seem to be the culprit in my case.

Answer (score 0):

For me, I never found the solution for this problem on the internet, so I tried to figure out myself how to fix this issue, basically, this is a problem with your services, Not windows services but 3rd party services on your system so you need to go to **msconfig** by hitting windows key + R and type "**msconfig**" then navigate to service section check for **"Hide windows services"**  and then disable all services there and reboot to see if the problem fixed or not, if it fixed then there must be one of the disabled services is the cause, so you will enable 10 of them at a time and reboot to see if the problem still there or not, it is a trial and error but you will find it eventually, for my experience with this problem I suggest that you search for any service related to USB thing and disable it first.

**the Fix for me is ( might apply to you as well )**

Do you have **VMware** in your system?
Yes: hit Windows key + R type **services.msc** hit enter, and search for "VMware USB Arbitration Service" double click and disable this service.

No: Try to clean boot your system, disable all services except windows services - there is a check box for that - and see if the problem persist, and follow what I have said above.

Comment: It was the "VMware USB Arbitration Service" for me. Thanks for the tip. Solved my year old problem.

Answer (score 0):

Had similar issue (several minutes to detect USB pen), tried everything suggested, all to no avail. In the end, it was caused by an sd card converter left plugged into the sd card slot! As soon as I removed it, bang, instant USB pen recognition, no long delays!